# Excel count if date range is active in a certain month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 date, a start date and end date. I want to be able to count if these were active through a certain month.

```
Row 1: start date 20/11/2020, end date 03/02/2021.
Row 2: start date 03/01/2021, end date 15/03/2021
Row 2: start date 12/01/2021, end date 31/03/2021,
```

The columns I have are the months and based on the above data this is the expected result.

```
Nov  1
Dec  1
Jan  3
Feb  3
Mar  2
```

Is there a formula that I can use to count this through a range of 100's of rows?

Comment: What have you tried?  What, specifically, is your problem in developing a formula? The usual algorithm is `start<=period_end` **AND** `end>=period_start`

Comment: Hi, I found a solution on here  using {SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(ROW(INDIRECT($A4 & ":" & IF($B4="",TODAY(),$B4))))>=YEAR(TODAY()))*(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A4 & ":" & IF($B4="",TODAY(),$B4))),"mmm")=C$2))}   This worked per month, I then tried to edit this for a week beginning a    {=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(ROW(INDIRECT($A4 & ":" & IF($B4="",TODAY(),$B4))))>=YEAR(TODAY()))*(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A4 & ":" & IF($B4="",TODAY(),$B4))),"dd/mm/yyyy")=C$2))} but this didn't.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method than what you posted in your comment.

Put your start/end dates in a **Table** and name it `StartEndTbl`

Create a column of months whereby

- Each entry is the first day of the month
- The column is formatted `mmm-yyy`

In the first cell (`F2` in this case), enter the formula:

```
F2: =SUM((StartEndTbl[Start]<=EOMONTH(E2,0))*(StartEndTbl[End]>=E2))
```

and fill down as far as needed

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, this worked really well. Is there an easy way to modify this (not my original ask) to count the days of the week. e.g. Nov 20th would be 10 days.  I might need to put this as a new question

Comment: @FuriousD Yes. That would require a different algorithm and, accordingly, would warrant a different question.  But wouldn't `Nov-2020` be `11` days?

Comment: ha, yes - I'll mock up a spreadsheet and send a better example under a new post.